# How to call whatsmate translation API on the Bowser?

Tags: api

subscribed to their API today, I was wondering about how I can call their API on the browser 
they already provided this, I tried a lot but I didn't get anything

See Their API Reference `https://whatsmate.github.io/api-reference/`

> > ```
> >     Translation Endpoints
> > 1. Translate text
> > Endpoint: POST /v1/translation/translate
> > Parameters required in JSON payload:
> > fromLang: String. The code representing the language of the supplied text.
> > toLang: String. The code representing the language you want the text to be translated to.
> > text: String. The piece of text you want to be translated.
> > List of language codes: See the next endpoint.
> > Response: String. The translated text.
> > ```